# finding the optimal purchase among different combinations

Tags: excel, mathematical-optimization

I have a list of products offered by different companies. I need to select the combination of companies/product that will minimaze my purchase.
The price is a total ( including the qty ) so the qty is not a variable.

So the answer should be {(company_A, product_X),...,(Company_B, product_Y)} i.e. for each column product to be purchased, which company shall I go for?

Also if possible to add a constraint: I am allowed to buy only X number of products from company A, Y number from company B etc...

Any hint how this can be done in excel or python plz

[image: inputs sample]

Tried with Excel but no simple solution foreseen.

Comment: I would do this with the Solver in Excel - can have constraints and set to maximize revenue or profit or minimize the costs. There are examples of doing similar with Solver on here.

Comment: If the qty is not a variable, how can you constrain on it?

Answer (score 0):

Insert this function in the next cell after the columns of prices. Change the range parameters according to the actual ones.

```
=INDEX($D5:$D9;MATCH(MIN(E5:E9);E5:E9; 0);1)
```

And the result

[image]